# Torrent download starts only for a few torrents, rest are still "connecting to peers" . Am I missing something?

Tags: bittorrent

I am using uTorrent via Tor.

I know it works because I can download torrents, but the problem is that downloads don't start for all torrents. Only some of them work.

The same torrents work for my friends who are not under a proxy network. What could be the reason for this?

[image: Screenshot, torrent #1 and #2 never start]

[image: uTorrent Connection Preferences]

[image: Proxy setings I use to connect tor browser]

Comment: > I am using xyzTorrent via Tor. Please don't unless torrents are the only way to get you an update for Tor or to download a distribution like Tails, while you couldn't otherwise. The reason it should be avoided is that you put load on the Tor network, which has not been designed for bulk downloading. It harms the network. Another reason is that people use it to share content illegally and this should be avoided to not stress the exit node operators and because it is illegal. Though I'm not sure if illegality is a concern depending on what's deemed to be illegal in some countries. Another reas

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will stop using torrents on Tor from now on.

Comment: The idea behind bittorrent is that everybody knows each other's IP address, so that everybody can connect to everybody else. (Peer-to-peer...) The idea behind Tor is pretty much the opposite: to hide your IP. When using bittorrent, you're broadcasting your IP address. Whether other peers connect to the IP address you give them, or the IP address they see you coming in from, both will likely fail (assuming you have not punched a hole in your firewall for this). So you're hurting your own anonymity **and** you're hurting the torrent, or at least not contributing to it.

Comment: Shouldn't the other peers get the IP address of the exit node, for the case that the actual IP doesn't get leaked? The exit will reject this traffic and the peers will fail, so it harms bittorrent as well.

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant to say: whether they connect to the exit node or to you, they will fail either way, which hurts the torrent.

Comment: I understand better, I understood before and your answer is/was correct. :)

Comment: You might check to see if the torrents which are failing to connect only contain UDP trackers. Tor is a TCP relay, meaning UDP traffic can't be tunneled through Tor (not sure how μTorrent handles connections that can't be proxied).

Answer (score 2):

Bittorrent over Tor isn't a good idea
https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea